# Return ids after upsert Slick

Tags: sql, scala, slick

I have a query that upserts the data to the database via Slick. I'd like to return the ids of the entities that were inserted. How can I do this using Slick in Scala.
Here's a current query and entity defined:

```
def upsertEntitiesReturn(models: Seq[Entity]): Future[Unit] =
    dbRun((models map (entities returning entities).insertOrUpdate),
      Seq("entities"))

  val entities = TableQuery[Entities]

  class Entities(tag: Tag)
    extends Table[Entity](tag, Some("service"), "entities") {

      private def id = column[String]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
      private def name = column[String]("name")
      private def description = column[Option[String]]("description")

     def `*`: ProvenShape[Entity] =
      (id,
       name,
       description
      ) <> (
        {case (
         id,
         name,
         description
         ) => Entity(
           id,
           name,
           description
         )
       }, (a: Entity) =>
         Some((
           a.Id,
           a.Name,
           a.Description
         ))
     )
  }
```

Comment: Use `(entities returning _.id)` instead.

Comment: @AminMal Will this allow to insert the data with all the fields and then retrieve ids?

Comment: It worked the last time I tried :D